# What is actually happening behind the scene when another security group is added as a source in a security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, aws-security-group

From [the documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRule)
it says

> When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, traffic is allowed from the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group for the specified protocol and port.

Is this something specific to AWS infrastructure?
I can visualize CIDR block rules from Security Group to iptables firewall pretty easily however, I'm having a bit hard time how this Security Group as a source is done in context to iptables.

Note: I'm not an advance user in iptables but I do know basics of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand in layman terms.

When you an address in which there is a PIN Code and you know where its taking you. So here you took PIN code to reference the exact location.

Similar way when you add another security group to your existing security group, it is just the reference. So when an its looking for your security group, it reference to another security group. So, it will do whatever Ingress rule is stated in that another security group.

Ex:
I have one security group sg-app1 and another as sg-web which has port 80 and port 443 entery to the world. Now when I attach sg-web to sg-app1, an instance associtaed with sg-app1 will be allowed on port 80 and port 443 to the world as per sg-web. (Because sg-web was attached to sg-app1)

Hope it helps.